# Disable resizing of textarea with SimpleMDE

Tags: jquery, html, css, simplemde

I'm using `SimpleMDE` as editor on my page. The code is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'img/favicon.png' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/reset.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-G0fIWCsCzJIMAVNQPfjH08cyYaUtMwjJwqiRKxxE/rx96Uroj1BtIQ6MLJuheaO9" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/fonts.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/media.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/jquery.tagit.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/tagit.ui-zendesk.css' %}"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/markjax.min.js' %}"></script>


</head>
<body>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="main_content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="main_page_content">
                        <div class="wall">
                            <div class="box_roundbox">
                                <div class="padd_box05">
                                    <form method="post" id="task_create_form">
                                        Description:
                                        <div class="padd_box_top1" name="description">
                                            <textarea name="description" class="task_create_textarea">{{ task.description }}</textarea>
                                        </div>

                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>

        if ($(".task_create_textarea").length) {
            var task_create_textarea_mde = new SimpleMDE({ element : $(".task_create_textarea")[0], spellChecker: false, previewRender: function(plainText, preview) {
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    markjax(plainText, preview);
                  }, 50);
                  return preview.innerHTML;
                } });
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

CSS classes:

```
.main  {
    padding-top: 3em;
}
.row  {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.wall  {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 3;
    margin-right: 2em;
}
.box_roundbox  {
    border: 0.15em solid #AAAAAA;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}
.padd_box05  {
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.padd_box_top1  {
    padding-top: 1em;
}
```

My problem is: when I type really long strings in `textarea` generated by `SimpleMDE`, it just enlarges uncontrollably. How to disable horizontal resizing of `padd_box_top1`? I tried `resize: none;`, but nothing changed.

Comment: 'resize: none' only works directly on the textarea element.

Comment: @PierreBurton, `SimpleMDE` somehow changes it so my styles stop working. Moreover, resizing by user is turned off by default, AFAIK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a max-width like this:

```
 .padd_box_top1 {
     max-width: 40%;
 }
```

This will prevent the textarea from enlarging, if you want a min-width as well you can add that too, just add: min-width: 25%; 
Change the amount of pixels to whatever you like.

Comment: Using predefined size in pixels is not exactly appropriate for the adaptive design

Comment: @NikitinRoman you're right, of course we can set any unit we want, for responsive design percentage will fit. I'll edit my answer thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The resize:none; will remove the possibility for the user to resize the textarea manually. But you want to disable the auto-resizing due to long strings. So this isn't what you should use.

I checked [the official website of SimpleMDE](https://simplemde.com/), and the examples in their homepage don't resize when I type very long strings [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCOPL.jpg).

What I can suggest is using a fixed width, or disable the max-width (max-width:none;).